# How to create the Lookup field in the Home Page Component

Tags: home-page-component

I want to create the lookup field in the homepage slide bar, like below

```
Order name : text field
Opportunity : Lookup field
Submit Button
```

How to create the lookup field and create the record when click the submit button using java script.

Comment: If you are good with Visualforce, and if your org is on summer14 already you should be able to create a visualforce sidebar component. You do not need javascript to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a sidebar VF page which does all the work for you.

Here is the link to a blog from Bob Buzzard which may prove useful.

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2010/09/visualforce-lookup.html

Here is the link to a blog from Jeff Douglas.

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/